# Need help with error in creating a dashboard report

Tags: civireport, dashlet

Trying to track down this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

It occurs any time the "available for dashboard" option is checked for a report and then the report is saved.  This is civicrm 4.6.4 on drupal 7.38, php 5.3.29 and mysql 5.1.56.

Tried to post the backtrace here, but stackexchange gives me the lovely "this looks like spam" flag. :-/

Tracing through the code, I can see that in CRM/Core/BAO/Dashboard.php, the addDashlet() function, the call to $dashlet->save(); is failing silently on line 459.  So then there is no record in the civicrm_dashboard table for the dashlet, and when it next tries to add records to civirm_dashboard_contact it fails on the foreign key index.

So I don't get why the dashlet save function would fail at all, let alone fail without an error.

Any help appreciated.